# Catching dialog name before being routed - middleware

Tags: node.js, botframework

I have a bot built with MS bot framework, using a library structure.

I'm trying to catch the dialog name + library of a message, **before** it is being routed to the dialog. (for analytics purposes)

Is there a middleware that can help me do that?

I tried the `routing` middleware of the `UniversalBot`, but it seems be running just before a dialog was choosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like `bot.onDisambiguateRoute` is the solution.

The var `route` contains the route name/library in that case, and has also the dialog arguments besides that. [see the docs for more info](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.irouteresult.html#routedata)

example code:

`bot.onDisambiguateRoute(function (session, routes) {
        // Route message as normal
        var route = builder.Library.bestRouteResult(routes, session.dialogStack(), bot.name);
        // *** log route
        if (route) {
            bot.library(route.libraryName).selectRoute(session, route);
        } else {
            // Just let the active dialog process the message
            session.routeToActiveDialog();
        }
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

One possible option here could be using the [ISessionMiddleware](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.isessionmiddleware.html).

```
 botbuilder: function (session, next) {
       console.log(session.message.text);
       next();
   }
```

This will allow you to have access to the session. This will execute once a message is bound to a particular session and gives the option of looking at a message and the state of the session (where user is in available dialogs, etc) then making a decision of how to proceed.

Comment: hey @Ezequiel Jadib, it seems the session doesn't contain the dialog it is being routed to (probably it runs before it was chosen)

Comment: How are you trying to see the dialog?

Comment: take a look at my answer